# Exception: The number of rows in the range must be at least 1

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am having trouble writing my json data to a google sheet - I get the exception "The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range."

I think the problem is with how the range is set - but I don't know how to fix it. I include a sample of the json data after this script:

```
  function getApi() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var url = "https://www.lexology.com/api/v1/track/clients/articles?companyId=1013419&limit=100";
  var params = {
         "contentType": "application/json",
         "headers":{"ApiKey": "MYAPIKEY"
                    },

         };

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
var dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); 
var dataSet = dataAll;
var rows = [],
data;
  

  for (i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {
    data = dataSet[i];
    rows.push([data.companyID, data.companyName, data.articles ]); 
  }
 Logger.log(dataSet)

  dataRange = sheet.getRange(3, 1, rows.length, 3); 
  dataRange.setValues(rows);
}
```

The json data looks like this:

```
{
  "companyId": 1013419,
  "companyName": "Cisco Systems Inc",
  "jurisdictions": [],
  "workAreas": [],
  "tags": [],
  "fromDate": "2021-01-10T00:00:00+00:00",
  "toDate": "2021-02-10T00:00:00+00:00",
  "articles": [
    {
      "date": "2021-01-04T00:00:00",
      "articleUrl": "https://www.lexology.com/library/detail.aspx?g=253372ab-8cce-47c9-853f-4a9953becc0d",
      "title": "USPTO and IMPI Announce Parallel Patent Grant Initiative",
      "summary": "Under the terms of the MoU, a parallel patent grant framework was instituted which allowed IMPI to leverage search and examination results from the USPTO when issuing a counterpart Mexican patent.",
      "firmName": "Casimir Jones SC",
      "topic": null,
      "jurisdictions": [
        "Mexico",
        "USA"
      ],
      "workAreas": [
        "Patents"
      ],
      "reads": 3,
      "prints": 0,
      "authorNameOrPhotoClick": 0,
      "articleContentLink": 0,
      "forwardedUsingMailTo": 0,
      "viewOriginal": 0
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-12-23T00:00:00",
      "articleUrl": "https://www.lexology.com/library/detail.aspx?g=2c23065f-8479-4343-a889-2a072465bedc",
      "title": "Why Everyone Is Patenting Software Inventions",
      "summary": "Finding the correct balance requires the assistance of a patent strategist with knowledge of what the patent examiner is likely to accept, and who is skilled in crafting the patent in a way that covers what competitors will need in order to compete.",
      "firmName": "Finnegan, Henderson, Farabow, Garrett & Dunner, LLP",
      "topic": null,
      "jurisdictions": [
        "USA"
      ],
      "workAreas": [
        "IT & Data Protection",
        "Patents"
      ],
      "reads": 3,
      "prints": 0,
      "authorNameOrPhotoClick": 0,
      "articleContentLink": 0,
      "forwardedUsingMailTo": 0,
      "viewOriginal": 0
    }
```

> ............EDIT.........
>
> I have fixed the typos in the code as pointed out, thank you.
>
> The output I am looking for is set out in [this sheet:](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c3_7D7KOwzR6mPNhKuCoGMNXODr9zgQG7qLzmpFfq6E/edit#gid=0&range=A1:F16)
>
> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c3_7D7KOwzR6mPNhKuCoGMNXODr9zgQG7qLzmpFfq6E/edit#gid=0&range=A1:F16

ALSO - when I do Logger.log(dataAll) it is not empty. I get the following:

```
12:58:42 AM Info    Logging output too large. Truncating output. {workAreas=[], articles=[{jurisdictions=[Mexico, USA], forwardedUsingMailTo=0.0, topic=null, prints=0.0, date=2021-01-04T00:00:00, authorNameOrPhotoClick=0.0, viewOriginal=0.0, workAreas=[Patents], title=USPTO and IMPI Announce Parallel Patent Grant Initiative, firmName=Casimir Jones SC, summary=Under the terms of the MoU, a parallel patent grant framework was instituted which allowed IMPI to leverage search and examination results from the USPTO when issuing a counterpart Mexican patent., reads=3.0, articleContentLink=0.0, articleUrl=https://www.lexology.com/library/detail.aspx?g=253372ab-8cce-47c9-853f-4a9953becc0d}, {articleUrl=https://www.lexology.com/library/detail.aspx?g=2c23065f-8479-4343-a889-2a072465bedc, authorNameOrPhotoClick=0.0, prints=0.0, jurisdictions=[USA], viewOriginal=0.0, topic=null, date=2020-12-23T00:00:00, reads=3.0, firmName=Finnegan, Henderson, Farabow, Garrett & Dunner, LLP, forwardedUsingMailTo=0.0, articleContentLink=0.0, summary=Finding the correct balance requires the assistance of a patent strategist with knowledge of what the patent examiner is likely to accept, and who is skilled in crafting the patent in a way that covers what competitors will need in order to compete., title=Why Everyone Is Patenting Software Inventions, workAreas=[IT & Data Protection, Patents]}, {date=2021-01-12T00:00:00, prints=0.0, reads=3.0, title=Election Ballot Verification - A Patent Subject Matter Eligibility Analysis, summary=v. CLS Bank Int., the court (1) determined that the claims were drawn to an abstract idea of “voting, verifying the vote, and submitting the vote for tabulation” and (2) found “no inventive concept in the claims sufficient to transform them into patent-eligible subject matter.” Recited at a high level of abstraction, the claims at issue before the court included one or more voting stations, each including a computer, a display, a printer, an input device, a ballot scanning machine, and a means for tabulating printed ballots., workAreas=[Litigation, Patents], jurisdictions=[USA], authorNameOrPhotoClick=0.0, forwardedUsingMailTo=0.0, topic=null, viewOriginal=0.0, articleContentLink=0.0, articleUrl=https://www.lexology.com/library/detail.aspx?g=544fc695-b8eb-4951-a19e-c2df4b7039b6, firmName=Baker & Hostetler LLP}, {authorNameOrPhotoClick=0.0, topic=null, forwardedUsingMailTo=0.0, date=2021-02-04T00:00:00, reads=3.0, articleUrl=https://www.lexology.com/library/detail.aspx?g=64b1aa84-d37f-4e80-9805-3509b48c1824, workAreas=[IT & Data Protection, Litigation], jurisdictions=[USA], title=Successful Dismissal of PayPal Class Action Over Breach Disclosures Serves as Risks Reminder, summary=Companies should consult closely with counsel when making a public announcement regarding a potential or confirmed data security incident to ensure they are thinking through the potential regulatory and litigation risks, whether a trading blackout period is appropriate during the period of investigation, and whether existing cybersecurity risk disclosures in the company’s public filings should be amended., firmName=Sheppard Mullin Richter & Hampton LLP, articleContentLink=0.0, prints=0.0, viewOriginal=0.0}, {topic=null, firmName=Wilmer Cutler Pickering Hale and Dorr LLP, articleUrl=https://www.lexology.com/library/detail.aspx?g=6cad7e90-ff4a-413f-9a4d-079a23c12a44, prints=0.0, reads=3.0, date=2020-12-22T00:00:00, title=Quick Takeaways: SolarWinds Cybersecurity Incident, viewOriginal=0.0, authorNameOrPhotoClick=0.0, articleContentLink=0.0, forwardedUsingMailTo=0.0, workAreas=[IT & Data Protection], summary=Certain versions of SolarWinds software updates that assist organizations in managing their computer networks were compromised by what some officials, such as the US Secretary of State and the US Attorney General, have indicated is a Russian intelligence agency., jurisdictions=[USA]}, {firmName=Reed Smith LLP, forwardedUsingMailTo=0.0, authorNameOrPhotoClick=0.0, summary=The Guidelines set out the law applicable to operations consisting in reading or writing data on users’ devices and clarify the CNIL’s approach, while the Recommendation aims to guide organisations in their compliance efforts by providing examples of practical methods that can be used, notably to collect consent., date=2021-01-22T00:00:00, title=Adtech regulatory round-up January 2021, articleUrl=https://www.lexology.com/library/detail.aspx?g=8973269a-306a-48d3-9b19-0e50a6647d96, articleContentLink=0.0, viewOriginal=1.0, jurisdictions=[Germany, France, United Kingdom, USA], topic=null, workAreas=[IT & Data Protection, Litigation], reads=3.0, prints=0.0}, {firmName=Sheppard Mullin Richter & Hampton LLP, reads=3.0, articleUrl=https://www.lexology.com/library/detail.aspx?g=8e3a8f46-982e-41ba-a4bc-9e8af57ac7db, forwardedUsingMailTo=0.0, summary=The second carve-out from the definition of protected information was for information known to the employee before he joined TGS, “as evidenced by Employee’s written records.” The Brown court took a particularly dim view of this exception, because it would mean that information which, by definition was not confidential before Brown began working at TSG, would become so unless Brown had written records proving he knew of it beforehand., authorNameOrPhotoClick=0.0, title=California Court Strikes Down Overbroad Confidentiality Agreement as a de facto Non-Compete, articleContentLink=0.0, prints=0.0, topic=null, viewOriginal=0.0, date=2021-01-05T00:00:00, workAreas=[Employment & Labor, Litigation], jurisdictions=[USA]},
```

Comment: I think that when I saw your sample JSON data (This JSON data is `dataAll`?) and your script, `rows` is `[]`. I think that this might be the reason of your issue. So in order to correctly understand about your goal, can you provide the sample output situation you expect using your sample JSON data? By this, I would like to think of the modification points in your script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Issue:

Apparently you can't get a range with `0` rows. In this method [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)), every parameter should be a number larger than `0`.

**Why is `rows.length`  `0`?**

The issue has to do with the fact that your `JSON` `dataSet` is not an array, therefore the `for` loop is terminated because `dataSet.length` is `undefined`. As a result `row.length` is zero because no values were added.

### Updated Solution:

Assuming the first row (headers) in your sheet is:

`companyId  companyName articles.date   articles.articleUrl articles.title  articles.summary`

```
function getApi() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const url = "https://www.lexology.com/api/v1/track/clients/articles?companyId=1013419&limit=100";
  const params = {
         "contentType": "application/json",
         "headers":{"ApiKey": "MYAPIKEY"
                    },

         };
         
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  const dataSet = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); 

  const data = 
              dataSet.articles.map((r,i)=>
              i==0?[dataSet.companyId,dataSet.companyName,r.date,r.articleUrl,r.title,r.summary]:
                   ["","",r.date,r.articleUrl,r.title,r.summary]
              );
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

Comment: In OP's script, `row` is `[]` which is one dimentional array, because the for loop is not run due to `dataSet.length` is `undefined` when the sample JSON data is used. So, I thought that to include these information and the information of the specification that 2 dimensional array is required to be used for `setValues` might be useful for OP and other users.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you a lot for your comment! if `dataSet` was an array and all the parameters correctly defined, then `rows` should be a 2D array because she pushes an array in the `for` loop. Is that correct? I improved the answer towards the solution, but we need some clarification from the OP. Please check also the final comments in my answer which are also wrong in the code.

Comment: I think that your direction is correct. If OP's JSON data is included in an array, `rows` is 2 dimensional array. In this case, OP's script occurs no error. But `data.articles` might not be the result OP expected. When I saw OP's question for the 1st time, from OP's error message, I thought that `rows` might be `[]`. From this, I supposed that OP was using the JSON data in OP's question. So I asked the sample output situation, that OP expected, from the JSON data in this question.

Comment: @Tanaike I think we can't further (at least I ) proceed if OP does not clarify the comments in my answer. Maybe I shouldn't post an answer, but I assumed the data part was correct and I focused on fixing exceptions which might have occured due to empty `responses`, but apparently many things went differently in this code.

Comment: Yes. I also think that to know the OP's expected result will lead to the clear modification points.

Comment: @Tanaike if OP replies feel free to post your own answer. I will remove mine then. I don't mind :)

Comment: Thank you. I think that your this answer is useful for not only OP but also other users. So when the modified script is added, the answer will be more useful. I would like to upvote this.

Comment: @Marios and Tanaike thank you so much your discussion has helped me also understand better. I think the problem is with my json array as I have used this exact script with another json dataset and it worked fine. What is a 2 dimensional array? Is that the problem here?

Comment: @Mardi-LouiseVanHeerden your json has a format of `{}` which is **not** an array. So, when calling `dataSet.length` you get `undefined` error back and `rows` does not get filled with data. Given this json, you can get only a single row of data. If you confirm that, I can offer a solution. Please also read the other comments. `data.articles` is not a single value but an array of json objects. What information do you need from `articles` ??

Comment: @Mardi-LouiseVanHeerden thanks for your edits. I will come back with a solution in a moment

Comment: @Marios thank you!  OK, I think I understand about the array. I accept I can only get one row of data. For data.articles I need need  |  articles.date   | articles.articleUrl    | articles.title    | articles.summary    |

Comment: @Mardi-LouiseVanHeerden check my updated answer. Confirm it if it worked for you.

Comment: It did THANK YOU! I will take it apart and learn from this. Thank you very much! @Marios

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to move the line from fig1[the line under the first row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3eXq.png) to fig2[the line under the second row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSDsK.png). It works for me!